# change params value before patch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a texfield in a form where a foreign key's value is displayed. now I want to update the value and save it to the DB. Here is the code:

for the form I use:

```
  f.text_field :port, :value =>@entry.port.number, class:"form-
  control", placeholder:"Port"
```

in the controller I am using a param method:

```
def entry_params
  params.require(:entry).permit(:description,:rule_id, :protocol_id,   
  :url, :port)
end
```

the update method looks like this:

```
def update
  @entry.url.name = params[:entry][:url]
  @entry.port.number = params[:entry][:port]
  if @entry.update(entry_params)
    flash[:success] = "Entry was successfully updated!"
    redirect_to entry_path(@entry)
  else
    render 'edit'
  end
end
```

but if I want try to save it, it shows this error:

```
Url(#70247237379440) expected, got "www.drive.google.com" which is an 
instance of String(#70247218839280)
```

Now my question is, (I'm relativ new to rails) how can I fix this? I know that it expect an object as a parameter but if I change the param like this:

```
params[:url] = @entry.url
```

it doesn't work.

Comment: I'm a little unclear on what you're asking here - the error looks related to a url, yet you're referencing assigning a `port` to an `entry` elsewhere. Happy to take a look if you're able to clarify things a little?

Comment: I use a form to create a new entry, a textfield to enter an Url -> creates new Url object. so its related. The same form is used to edit the entry. but if I try to edit the related Url in the form (entering in the texfield) I cant save the entry correctly, as you see.

Comment: Gotcha, cheers @vaekek

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two approaches I can think of here, depending on exactly what you're looking to achieve.

If you're looking to assign an `entry` a new `url` based on a string params, you can use something like the following:

`@entry.url = Url.find_by_name(params[:entry][:url])`

Depending on your models' setup, if there's a `url_id` column on your entries, you might be better off using a `select` field on this, passing the URL's name and id to the options. If you can add this info to your question, I can update / rule this out as needed.

If you're just looking to update the URL via the entry's form, you'd be best looking at using [accepts_nested_attributes_for](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html).

Doing this, you can directly update the associated objects through the parent's form. If this sounds like the right approach for you, let me know and I can provide more detail :)

Edit: as per your comment, is sounds like this is the option you're after. So, you'd need something like the following:

**entry.rb**

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :url
```

In the form:

```
...
f.nested_fields_for :url do |url_fields|
  url_fields.text_field :name
end
...
```

And you'll need to update the params in your controller to accept these nested fields. I can't remember the exact for they take, but it's something like:

```
def new / edit # whichever you're in 
  ...
  @entry.build_url unless @entry.url.present?
end

def entry_params
  params.require(:entry).permit(:description,:rule_id, :protocol_id,   
  :port, url_attributes: [:name])
end
```

(It might be you need an empty array or a hash for `url_attributes`.)

That'll then directly update the associated url. FYI if you've not got an associated URL, you'll need to build one using `@entry.build_url` in the controller.

Hope this helps - if you've any questions / details to help clarify, let me know and I'll update as needed.

Comment: Thanks! I want to update the related URL via the entry's form(not to create a new one and relate it to the new one, as I do atm). the entry belongs to an url(so there is a colum "url_id").  @SRack

Comment: OK great - that should be the latter approach highlighted there. I'll pop a little more info in my question in a min!

Comment: I did it that way:
`@entry.url.name = params[:entry][:url]
  @entry.url.save` in the controller, but in the view, now I got errors in the create action because I can't refer to a null object. but how can I display the value then correctly? see my question how i render the view.

Comment: I've updated my answer to reflect this @vaekek - if the entry doesn't have a url already, you'll need to build one in the controller so it's available in `fields_for`. Give that a go and see if it helps :)

Comment: Great, glad to hear it!